# Justification of the relationship $s/S<\lambda/d$ for interference fringes to be seen

Tags: optics, interference, double-slit-experiment

[My book] (NCERT Class 12 Physics text; Chapter no.:10 - Wave Optics)
(https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/leph202.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjcz4PR1-6CAxXHQfUHHVlYCuoQFnoECAgQAQ&usg=AOvVaw301VEzXnurxZ3o6DPXUjP-)

states that the condition $$s/S < \lambda/d$$ (where $S$ is the distance of the source from the slitted plane and $s$ is the size of the source)  must be satisfied for interference fringes to be seen.

It further says that when this condition is not satisfied  interference patterns produced by different parts of the source overlap and no fringes are seen.

What I ultimately understood is that when the size of the source increases, interference patterns produced by different parts of the source overlap and no fringes are seen.

Please correct me if my understanding is flawed and provide a detailed intuitive explanation for the condition mentioned above. (Rigorous mathematical proof is not encouraged as I am just a high schooler)

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will edit my post to include those.